# Can some one help me with sed command?

Tags: command-line, scripts

```
{   
    echo
    finde="LOG_$(tac /var/log/lol.log | grep -m 1 "ber" | cut -d " " -f 11 | sed -e 's/\,//g' | sed 's/ber=//' && date | cut -d " " -f 2,3,4,5,7  | sed -e 's/\ //g' | sed -e 's/\://g' && echo .tgz)"
    echo $finde      
    ls | while read file; do mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed  -e 's|FEITO|"${finde}"|g')" ; done 
    }
```

Why this change the name of the File to Feito and dont change to sed command?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It will help if you can edit your question to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand what you're doing without access to the input files, but a couple quick suggestions: (1) replace `ls | while read file ; do ... done` with the simpler and safer `for file in * ; do ... done` (2) I doubt you really want `sed  -e 's|FEITO|"${finde}"|g'` since the single quotes will prevent the variable from being expanded and will interpret the double quotes as literal parts of the replacement—probably remove the single quotes and use something other than `|` for the delimiter, but I'm not sure, again, because I don't know what the files are like.

Comment: Thank you for your help!